# How do I compare group means to individual observations and make a new TRUE/FALSE column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr, outliers

I am new to R and this is my first post on SO - so please bear with me.

I am trying to identify outliers in my dataset. I have two data.frames:

(1 - original data set, 192 rows): observations and their value (AvgConc)

(2 - created with dplyr, 24 rows): Group averages from the original data set, along with quantiles, minimum, and maximum values

I want to create a new column within the original data set that gives TRUE/FALSE based on whether (AvgConc) is greater than the maximum or less than the minimum I have calculated in the second data.frame. How do I go about doing this?

Failed attempt:

```
Outliers <- Original.Data %>%
 group_by(Status, Stim, Treatment) %>%
 mutate(Outlier = Original.Data$AvgConc > Quantiles.Data$Maximum | Original.Data$AvgConc <  Quantiles.Data$Minimum) %>%
 as.data.frame()
```

Error: Column `Outlier` must be length 8 (the group size) or one, not 192

Comment: How do you map `Original.Data` with `Quantiles.Data` ? Is there some common column between them? You can share first few rows of both the datasets using `dput` i.e `dput(head(Quantiles.Data))` and `dput(head(Original.Data))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, we need to remove the `Quantiles.Data$` by doing a join with 'Original.Data' `by` the 'Status', 'Stim', 'Treatment'

```
library(dplyr)
Original.Data %>%
   inner_join(Quantiles.Data %>% 
              select(Status, Stim, Treatment, Maximum, Minimum)) %>%
   group_by(Status, Stim, Treatment) %>%
   mutate(Outlier = (AvgConc > Maximum) |(AvgConc <  Minimum)) %>%
   as.data.frame()
```

Comment: Gave that a shot, ran into this error:
Error in select(., Status, Stim, Treatment, Maximum, Minimum) : 
  unused arguments (Status, Stim, Treatment, Maximum, Minimum)

Comment: @iastatecy you havent' showed any example, so it was based on just my gut feeling that there could be those columns.  If you can update your post with some simple example and expceted output, it would be easier to debug

Comment: Realized I don't need the group_by line, so the joining portion works and the columns are labeled correctly, but when I get to the mutate line I get this error: Error in mutate(Outlier = (AvgConc > Maximum) | (AvgConc < Minimum)) : 
  object 'AvgConc' not found

Comment: @iastatecy in your code, there is `Original.Data$AvgConc`, so it is not clear how you have that column name without the column present in the data.  Can you please check `colnames(Original.Data)`

Comment: The AvgConc column is in the original data. I tried inner_join and was able to get it to work!